# How to setup Azure Data sync for On-Premise database?

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I want to sync all my on-premise database data to SQL Azure database and recently came across SQL Azure Data sync in the Azure management portal.

I have followed the steps on the site http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/

1. I installed SQL server 2012 and SQL server agent on my on-premise server.
2. Created Database in both On-premise server and Azure management portal.
3. Created an agent in management portal then I copied the agent key and pasted in my Data Sync agent Window at On-premise server.
4. Added my on-premise database in Data Sync Agent client.
5. Created Sync group for cloud database and On-premise database (agent client).
6. This what I am seeing, even though I enabled the sync group for every five minutes.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: what are you seeing? did you intend to post an image here?

Answer (score 0):

Use DAC BACPAC to migrate a database to windows azure sql:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156148.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2639.how-to-use-data-tier-application-import-and-export-with-a-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

In short:

1. Install Data-tier Application Framework (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39976)
2. Using SQL Server Management Studio (ssms) connect to your source database and export it to .bacpac file
3. Using SSMS connect to your destination db and import it from .bacpac file